# Ryuuzetsu's Kekkei Genkai

Tags: naruto

In the 5th Naruto Shippuden Movie "Blood Prison", the character Ryuuzetsu is introduced. The strange thing I noticed were that her eyes had the same appearance as those of the Rinnegan:

[image]

Is this the Rinnegan? If so, how did she acquire it and why can't she use any Rinnegan related techniques? If it isn't is it related to her clan Kekkei Genkai (or does she have 2 Kekkei Genkai's):

[image]

Comment: more like doujutsu that doesn't exist in canon.

like Ranmaru

Comment: all the wikia says is that her eyes have *"multiple circular patterns much like Pain's Rinnegan"* but not sure if the Rinnegan was conceived in the manga before or after the movie. while i haven't seen the movie or enough of the series to be 100% accurate Kekkei Genkai eyes generally look different in some way when activated compared to their "idle mode" (like how those with the Byukugan generally have white yes but get like an extra circular pattern when activated)

Answer (score 1):

Whether Ryūzetsu's eyes are related to her [Kekkei Genkai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABzetsu%27s_Kekkei_Genkai) or not is unknown, as she is the only person seen with this ability

> This unnamed kekkei genkai apparently allows the user to perform Reincarnation Ninjutsu as it allowed Ryūzetsu to perform the Dragon Life Reincarnation technique. It was seen only in Naruto the Movie: Blood Prison and Ryūzetsu was the only known user. Other details, such as whether it was common or rare and whether any other technique could be performed using it, are unknown.

And while [Ryūzetsu's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABzetsu) eyes look very similar to the Rinnegan

> Ryūzetsu had fair skin, waist-length white hair that is covered by a green bandana that has a long curved white stripe which had belonged to Muku and **grey eyes with multiple circular patterns much like Pain's Rinnegan.**

they are not the same. We know the ways to obtain the [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) are

> 1. The Rinnegan can typically be awakened by gaining Hagoromo's chakra either by reproducing it from combining the chakra of Hagoromo's sons, Indra and Asura, or by directly receiving chakra from Hagoromo himself
> 2. As with any dōjutsu, the Rinnegan can be transplanted into others

Additional, those with the Rinnigan can master any jutsu and all 5 chakra natures

> One who possesses the Rinnegan can easily master any jutsu as well as all five nature transformations

However Ryūzetsu is only shown using Fire Style.